# Can't access postgres database, query doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

```
var client = new pg.Client(clientConfig);
var queryConfig = {text: 'SELECT messageID FROM privateMessages WHERE message = $1',
                    values: ['test']};

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    client.connect();
    response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
    client.query(queryConfig, function(err, result) {

      if (err){
        console.log("error");
      }

      response.end('You are visitor number'); 
    });
    client.end();  

});

server.listen(3001)
```

The query being made is valid. But the callback function doesn't seem to work. Why isn't the database being accessed? This has been tried with insertions.